# How to use an animation created in Adobe After Effects in an Android Layout for an application without compromising the quality of the animation?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, after-effects

I have created a fairly advanced opening screen animation for my app in After Effects. I am wondering if there is a way to import it without compromising on the quality. I will be happy to know if there is any other framework that allows it rather than just native development.

I have already tried Lottie Library but it seems the animation is too complex to be rendered by it. So far I have only been able to import the animation as a GIF and that too in very poor quality.

```
<pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
    android:id="@+id/gif"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="600dp"
    android:src="@drawable/logoanim3" />
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  Please share the relevant code snippets you have tried so far.

Comment: Why didn't Lottie work for you? I've used it with a lot of animations in one of my apps and it has worked perfectly. No matter how complex the animation was. Might be a stupid question but, did you export the animation as a .json?

Comment: @Rik Yes, of course, I did export it as a .json file. But it was not rendering on the emulator or my device. Only the animation background appeared and the logo which was supposed to enter with a swirling animation did not appear.